# Spark UDF function fail on Standalone Spark

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-spark

I have spring boot java application **myapp.jar** with something udf function.

**SparkConfuration.java**

```
 public SparkSession sparkSession() {
     SparkSession session = SparkSession
             .builder()
             .appName("uniloader-spark-master")
             .master(sparkMaster)
             .config("spark.jars", sparkJars)
             .getOrCreate();
     log.info("Spark jars for control: " + sparkJars);
     session.sqlContext().udf().register("to_integer", new ToIntegerUdf(), DataTypes.IntegerType);
     return session;
 }
```

**ToIntegerUdf.java**

```
public class ToIntegerUdf implements UDF2<Object, Object, Integer> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 165436543635L;


    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BaseFilesUtils.class);

    @Override
    public Integer call(Object valueObj, Object delimiterObj) {
        try {
            log.info("value = " + valueObj);
            log.info("delimiter = " + delimiterObj);
            if (valueObj == null || delimiterObj == null) {
                return null;
            }
            String value = String.valueOf(valueObj);
            String delimiter = (String) delimiterObj;
            String doubleAsString = value.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(delimiter), ".");
            return new BigDecimal(doubleAsString).setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).intValue();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error while to_integer transformation for " + valueObj + ". Details:", e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

sparkJars contains path to myJar.jar.

Application build with Maven. Spark library version is **3.02** and scala version is **2.12.10**.

When I running application on Spark Standalone **3.0.2** I have an error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF.f of type scala.Function1 in instance of org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2301)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2268)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2126)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2344)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2268)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2126)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:2032)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1613)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2344)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2268)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2126)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2344)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2268)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2126)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:2032)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1613)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:2032)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1613)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2344)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2268)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2126)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:2032)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1613)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2344)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2268)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2126)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2344)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2268)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2126)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2344)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2268)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2126)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:465)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:423)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:488)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2235)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2126)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2344)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2268)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2126)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2344)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2268)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2126)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:465)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:423)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:462)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:465)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

In spark worker log I see, worker fetch myJar:

`21/03/23 19:33:24 INFO Executor: Fetching spark://demo.phoenixit.ru:39597/jars/myJar.jar with timestamp 1616517199949`

I think problem with either dependency, or submitting, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Not sure this is an answer, so have a look at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-29497 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-25047

Comment: Thanks for comment. I saw this topic, but they didn't help :(

Comment: Are you sure the scala version that run your Java app and the scala version that compiled / run your spark cluster's Spark instances are on par ?

Comment: Hmm.. scala-library version's in my app is 2.12.10 and spark's jars folder has scala-library 2.12.10. Is it enough to be sure?

Comment: That's at least a very good start. Sorry I have no more idea to contribute.

Comment: I've confused a little about ScalaUDF.f of type scala.Function1, cause my function is UDF2, so, in my mind, it should cast to Function2..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it.

The problem was with the spring-boot-maven-plugin. Spark standalone can't get info about UDF's if I use this plugin.

When I replaced plugin with maven-shade-plugin, everythinh worked correct