# Clarification on Spark Scala UDFs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I have a few questions regarding spark UDFs

1. What is the difference between `spark.udf.register` syntax and `udf`?

What I have explored so far is that `spark.udf.register` allows me to pass a function that has a name, i,e.

```scala
def isLessThanAverage(revenue: Double) = {
  revenue <= average match {
    case true => "BelowAverage"
    case false => "AboveAverage"
    }
  }
```

2. I am encountering a weird error using `udf`.

```scala
val lessThanAverage_udf = udf((revenue: Double) => revenue <= average match {case true => "BelowAverage" case false => "AboveAverage"})
```

The above code block works. And I can apply it to a dataframe, i.e.

```scala
val sales_marker = sales_by_date_log.withColumn("IsBelowAverage",lessThanAverage_udf(col("Revenue")))
sales_marker.show()
```

However, if i use

```scala
val lessThanAverage2 = (revenue: Double) => revenue <= average match {case true => "BelowAverage" case false => "AboveAverage"}
val lessThanAverage_UDF = udf(lessThanAverage2)
val sales_marker2 = sales_by_date_log.withColumn("IsBelowAverage",lessThanAverage_UDF(col("Revenue")))
sales_marker2.show()
```

I get the error below:

```
Job aborted due to stage failure.
Caused by: ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field line425abd1ae5ca416b8e9fe842b8ff8fc6532.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.lessThanAverage2 of type scala.Function1 in instance of line425abd1ae5ca416b8e9fe842b8ff8fc6532.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw
```

EDIT : I'm using spark 3.0.1 and scala 2.12.10

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66777971/spark-udf-function-fail-on-standalone-spark and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-29497

Comment: Registration is just so that you can use it with Spark SQL. There's no need to if you don't need it. Can we have more info like which Scala and Spark version it is failing on?

Comment: Edited the post to show version. So if i understand you correctlt, the spark.udf.register will allow me to use the function in actual SQL queries and the scala API, while the udf() syntax only works for the scala API?

Comment: Yup, but the Scala APIs are safer because it gets checked by the compiler (Spark is not that type-safe, but still better than nothing). You should avoid string queries unless they are only known on runtime.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new (and my background is in Python) string queries means the actual sql query right? Anyway, thanks. 1 is cleared for me. 2 is a bit weird.

Comment: Can you provide a full runnable example that reproduces the error? In particular we need to look at the closures that are formed and what needs to be serialised.

Comment: Yeah I'm referring to the actual sql queries. To the compiler they are just strings.